# Protect Excel With Allow Sort and Allow Auto Filter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I'm using **EPPLUS.dll** for doing my excel works
I tried to protect the worksheet using **AllowSort** and **AllowAutoFilter** Properties but it's not working.

```
worksheet.Protection.AllowSort = true;
worksheet.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;
worksheet.Protection.SetPassword("password");
worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
```

I tried Below Code too but i didn't get my desired result

```
worksheet.Column(1).Style.Locked = true;
```

Epplus Lock Cells By default and Locking Cells will not Fix my Problem; the only thing I need is a **protected or read-only** cell while sorting and **Filtering Allowed**

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i Found was, using Visual Basic Code inside of that Excel Document which locked right-click and copy-paste options.
unfortunately before excel opens the documents, that asks something about dangerous scripts and offer to disable running scripts.
at last i was impossible in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the `worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;` to be the first statement in your block of code. Perhaps this is overriding your previous statements.

https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelSheetProtection.cs

The below has worked for me in the past, as in it will protect the worksheet, i.e. make it read only

```
        worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
        worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
        worksheet.View.FreezePanes(2, 1); // freeze header row
        worksheet.Protection.AllowSort = true;
        worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFilter = true;
        worksheet.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;
```

I think to password protect it, it has to be against the package not the worksheet.

So use the .Save overload if saving the package.

```
package.Save("password");
```

Or if you're saving as a ByteArray then

```
package.GetAsByteArray("password");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Answer Bro, I don't wanna set a password on my file, I made this program for taking some reports and these reports will be protected for low permissions but I want to make them free to use AutoFilter and Sorting